# how to write regular expression replaces zero with empty string and make sure that there is not leading digits

Tags: python, regex

i want a regular expression that replaces 0 * x ** n with 0 but i want to make sure that there is no number before the 0

i want the replacement in this formula

```
0 * x**2 + 20 * x**1
```

i want to replace 0 * x ** 2 with ''

i have written a regular expression but it replaces all zeros multiplied by x ** 2 it removed the zero after '2' in '20'

this is my regular expression

```
[+]?[ ]?0 [*] [a-z][*]{2}\d+
```

thank you

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? `str.split` can do this for you quite well

Comment: i want it to be a regex iam using re.sub()

Comment: So, you have this formula in a string? `0 * x**2 + 20 * x**1` Or is it Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the pattern:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'(^|\s)0 \* x\*\*([0-9]+) [\-+] ')
```

And this is how you replace with regex:

```
the_str = '0 * x**2 + 20 * x**1'
new_str = r.sub('', the_str)
```

Note that this will not clear last member if it is a zero. That would leave a handing "+" from the previous member, so it should be handled separately.

Also won't match "0 * x**-2", the negative exponent. This is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Pattern breakdown:

```
'(^|\s)0 \* x\*\*([0-9]+) [\-+] '
 ------- -- -----________ -----
    |_____|___|______|_____|____ match zero that is preceeded by beggining of the string or a space, to awoid matching things like "10 * x**2"
          |   |      |     |
          |___|______|_____|____ match asterisk, needs to be escaped because it's a special char in regex syntax
              |      |     |
              |______|_____|____ match literal x**
                     |     |
                     |_____|____ match one or more (that's what "+" means) chars in range of 0-9 (i.e. digits)
                           |
                           |____ match - or +, minus should be escaped here since it indicates a range of chars (as in [0-9])
Spaces match spaces.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import re
string = "0 * x**2 + 20 * x**1";
string = re.sub(r'([^0-9]|^)0 \* [a-z]\*\*[0-9]+', '0', string)
print(string)
```

Output:

```
0 + 20 * x**1
```

The pattern matches a non digit char or the begin of the line `([0-9]|^)` followed by the sequence of chars to replace: `0 \* x\*\*[0-9]+`.